# How can I retract or revoke my decision on a suggested edit review?

Tags: support, review, suggested-edits

How can I retract or revoke my decision on a suggested edit review?

I accepted an edit suggestion that, at that time, looked sensible to me. After I accepted the edit, it clicked to me that it was not right. I tried to revoke or retract my decision but I could not find how.

Is there a way of doing it?

Comment: Do you specifically want to change your decision on the review? Is there a reason why rolling the edit back isn't a solution here?

Comment: @Miniman Well, I really don't know. The thing is that when I accepted the edit a second person rejected it. Thus, it created a kind of a limbo for the edit: it was not published so I couldn't revert the edit, but also I couldn't support the rejection on the edit by retracting or revoking my decision.

Answer (score 5):

### I don't believe you can retract that approval-vote.

[What are the limits on how I can cast, change, and retract votes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5212/311001) doesn't say anything about edit-approval votes, and neither can any other meta.SE questions about "edit" "approve" "vote" and "retract," "revoke," "rescind," or "take-backsies."

### But you can *revert* the edit.

At the bottom of the post should be a clickable link: "edited [$TIME] ago." Clicking there brings you to the post's revision history.

Look to the most-recent version of the post you like--in this case probably the second-to-last post. Click "rollback."

I don't believe there's a way to leave an edit-comment on a rollback, so I suggest you leave one on the main post explaining why you object to the edit. (That way if there ever is some reason to dig through the post's revision history others aren't left wondering why this one reversion happened.)

Comment: In this case too the final decision on the edit was “reject”, so there's no rollback necessary. The only effect is having a erroneous “accept” in one's personal review history.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Does that display as a scarlet R on their profile?

Comment: @KorvinStarmast It does factor into the (invisible, non-scarlet) “is this user reviewing like a reasonable person?” calculation the site does (via a secret formula they won't tell us, to prevent gaming it), but a few erroneous review votes won't matter unless they're already skating on the borderline. FWIW I haven't noticed anyone on RPG fall on the wrong side of that calculation yet.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Heh, that was intended as a jest, but I forgot the smilie so I learned that we have yet another metric.  Cool!  Unintended learning is still learning.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Sorry, I tend to straight-face things when speaking in the capacity of a mod. I caught the jest. :)